# how to receive object (on iphone side)returned by webservice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, xcode, soap

in xcode i want to call webservice whose return value is object ?
1. what will be the SOAP message to call this web service ?
2. how xcode receive this object and use?

right now i have one method which return only string and i know how to call that by use of SOAP, but i dont know if it is change in case of object..

thank you in advance

Comment: Please show some code, where u are stuck. The question is too generic to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a webservice has to return any kind of standard XML.

If your webservice conforms strictly to SOAP it will return SOAP-XML message like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap:Header>
 </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
   <m:GetStockPrice xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
   <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
   </m:GetStockPrice>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

for more information see [SOAP on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)

Comment: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"  
  "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope \n"    
  "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"    
  "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"   \n"   
  "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org  /soap/encoding/\" \n"  
  "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"    
  "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"    
  "<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"    
  "<status xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"  
  "</status> \n"    
  "</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"    
  "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"

Comment: till now its work fine as status method till now returns only string but now i want status method should return string array or may be object in future ....so   my question is that should i have to change my SOAP message or when i receive this array /object how should i use this to display

Comment: ok, i figure out, if array is returned from web service than i dont have to change my SOAP message

Answer (score 0):

ok, i figure out, if array is returned from web service than i dont have to change my SOAP message